# Finding $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\frac{n^p \sin^2(n!)}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

It is given that $p > 0$. I did this question by first taking $n$ common and then I was getting answer as infinity but the answer in the book is given as $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. Please also use MathJax to edit your mathematical terms and symbols: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with $\sin^2(n!)$. It will fluctuate in the interval $(0, 1)$ (open interval). It will never be 0 or 1 for any $n > 0$ because $n! \neq k \pi/2$ for any $n$ and any integer $k$. Anyway, it is bounded and positive, and it will only have an impact on the limit if the rest of the expression converges to neither 0 nor $\pm \infty$.

We can rewrite the rest, $$\frac{n^p}{n+1} = \frac{n^{p-1}}{1+1/n},$$ where we see that the denominator will approach 1 as $n$ approaches $\infty$. Hence, to understand the limit we now only need to understand the behaviour of $n^{p-1}$. For $0 < p < 1$, it's limit is 0 and hence the limit of the entire expression is also 0. For $p = 1$ the limit is undefined because $n^0 = 1$ and the only factor not equal to 1 is $\sin^2(n!)$, which fluctuates. For $p > 1$, the limit is $\infty$.

Your textbook is correct for $0 < p < 1$, but not for $p \ge 1$.